# Calculate and study volatility time series

Tags: volatility, time-series, auto-correlation, anomalies, low-volatility

I am trying to study a **time series**. I have 10-year **daily close prices** for some stocks, so my time series is very simple: each day I have a close price for my company. The question is: how can I want to study **volatility**, so here's what I did:

- calculate the log returns
- compute volatility

From to this point on, I'm lost. Here's some of my ideas, but I need a confront and some advices:

1. is it statistically good to run **ADF test** and **KPSS test** and say "ok, my volatility is stationary / non-stationary"? **Which hypothesis should I do (and check) on stationarity?**
2. is it statistically good to compute **autocorrelation** in order to say "ok, my volatility is persistent/ non-persistent"? I can't really interpret the results I obtain: there are many numbers, but **I can't obtain a final result for the whole series**. How can I do it? I don't want to have to look at plots to have the final answer, since I will repeat this work for about 100 different time series...
3. Do you know how can I obtain a **confront between low-volatility, high-volatility and normal-volatility**? I would like to have a statistical measure or confront, but I cannot find anything (I would like to exclude arima, arch and garch models since I cannot do them). Is it correct to have the three calculated and plotted during the same period? How can I do that?

Sorry for the very long and articulated question, but I have been working on this for a while and I really can't find clear tutorials or hints and I am not able to do this alone...

EDIT:
After a useful comment, here's something I did about **autocorrelation**

a. I computed the autocorrelation function on the time series. From almost 3441 records, I got
[1.        , 0.98477797, 0.96781082, 0.9514661 , 0.93459373,
0.9176652 , 0.90032963, 0.88131626, 0.85938358, 0.83661734,
0.81445237, 0.79271494, 0.77129042, 0.75047027, 0.72866826,
0.70386183, 0.67833892, 0.65411195, 0.62999035, 0.60672692,
0.58538626, 0.56349308, 0.53889435, 0.51342648, 0.48940659,
0.46608168, 0.44405652, 0.42406814, 0.40413679, 0.38250615,
0.36066609, 0.35314497, 0.34682382, 0.3412075 , 0.3378708 ,
0.33433299]

b. I divided these results by the lenght of acf results (which is 36), obtaining [0.02777778, 0.02735494, 0.02688363, 0.02642961, 0.02596094,
0.0254907 , 0.02500916, 0.02448101, 0.02387177, 0.02323937,
0.02262368, 0.02201986, 0.02142473, 0.0208464 , 0.02024079,
0.01955172, 0.01884275, 0.01816978, 0.01749973, 0.01685353,
0.01626073, 0.01565259, 0.01496929, 0.01426185, 0.01359463,
0.01294671, 0.0123349 , 0.01177967, 0.01122602, 0.01062517,
0.0100185 , 0.00980958, 0.00963399, 0.00947799, 0.0093853 ,
0.00928703]

c. I plotted these numbers, getting the result in the image here below.  What do you think about it? Do you think it is correct? I'm not sure about how to interpret its meaning, do you have any advice/observation?

[image: autocorrelation]

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/556241/calculate-and-study-volatility-time-series) on Cross Validated.

Comment: (2): IMO, the ACF function is a fine way to illustrate whether volatility is persistent, by looking at the decay-rate of the positive autocorrelations. Often you don't put too much effort into highlighting this feature since this is an empirical stylized fact that is depicted many places in the literature. If you have one asset-class (eg. equities only) you can average the autocorrelations across asset dimension and then plot the average autocorrelations, hence giving you one plot to explain the persistence for all of your stocks.

Comment: Hi @Pleb, thanks for answering me. I have one question: what if I can't use plots to get my results? Is there a numerical way to get the same answer as seeing the plot?

Comment: You can output the lags in a table. What is the reason you cannot make a plot?

Comment: I need to make this job for 100+ time series. I need to make it fastly and automatized (possibly), so I can't just plot each time series and look at it... Suppose I put the lags in a table, do you have suggestions on what to do after it?

Comment: It was not my point to plot the autocorrelations for each stock,... If we assume you have 100+ equity time-series, you can calculate the ACF lags for each of their corresponding volatilities, then average out the lags across the asset dimension. This gives you the average persistence across your stocks. The averaged lags can be visualised in a typical "ACF-style" plot, hence giving you **one plot** to explain the average persistence across 100+ equity time-series. If you have time-series of many different asset-classes this method is not valid.

Comment: Can you link me some source of this? I think I'm getting your point, but I would like to read some tutorial and see it in order to understand how to implement this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132414/discussion-between-pleb-and-user96624).

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve here? what question are you trying to answer? It sounds like you a belt full of great tools; but you're not sure if you want to build a book-shelf or a chest of drawers ;-) happy to help if I can.